# Firebase Auth object being destroyed on orientation change

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
FirebaseAuth fbAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
fbAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(......etc
```

When user changes orientation the `fbAuth` object is destroyed and it doesn't look like you can use `onSaveInstanceState`.

Any ideas on how to resurrect it after orientation change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

FirebaseAuth is a singleton object.  There is only one for your entire app.  Just get it again with `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` whenever you need it.  That is the usual expectation for objects that you obtain through a static method called `getInstance()`.

Comment: OK - but then fbAuth.getCurrentUser() will then be equal to null.

Comment: Are you suggesting to log the user back in using fbAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(..?

Comment: No, use an auth listener or call getCurrentUser to find out what you need to do.

Comment: getCurrentUser() returns null after orientation change....thats the whole problem.

Comment: Maybe I can try using auth listener as per your recommendation

Comment: It only returns null when no user is logged in.  If you have specific reproduction steps that show otherwise, then it's a bug.

Comment: Interesting...so youre saying that fbAuth.getCurrentUser() should not change from correctly returning user...to instead returning null.....after user has changed orientation?

Comment: FirebaseAuth is a singleton, and it maintains global state.  Orientation change should mean nothing to it.

Comment: Worked it out....I was signing out of Firebase in the onDestroy() method which was being triggered on orientation change.  You helped alot, thanks

Comment: Ah, yeah, signout is mostly meant to be used when the end user expresses intent to so.

Answer (score 2):

During android orientation change the following methods get called:

```
onPause();
onSaveInstanceState();
onStop();
onDestroy();

onCreate();
onStart();
onResume();
```

You can grab a new instance of firebase Auth in the on resume or on start:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() { 
    fbAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}
```

Comment: OK - but then fbAuth.getCurrentUser() will then be equal to null.

Comment: Are you suggesting to log the user back in using fbAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(..?

Comment: Worked it out....I was signing out of Firebase in the onDestroy() method which was being triggered on orientation change.  You helped alot, thanks